# order_by queries in SQLAlchemy ... how to use NULLS LAST (for both ASC and DESC) with sqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm currently having some difficulty in migrating some chained query and sorting operations from postgresql to sqlite. (My DB only has one table, and will only have a maximum of around 50,000 rows so sqlite seems a better fit, not relationships, just a flat table).

However, I need some help inchaining a when's sorting query to a nulls last to sqlite.

My query is setup as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import case
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query

def perform_order_by_type(self, query: Query) -> Query:
        whens = {
            "Other": 4,
            "*": 3,
            "**": 3,
            "*Ass": 3,
            "OCl": 2,
            "GCl": 2,
            "G": 1,
            "Cl+N": 0,
            "PN": 0,
            "HII": 0,
            "DrkN": 0,
            "EmN": 0,
            "Neb": 0,
            "RfN": 0,
            "SNR": 0,
        }

        sort = case(value=Body.type, whens=whens).label("type")

        return query.order_by(sort)
```

I then order by `.order_by(self.model.m)` whereby m is a `Float` column, the first sorting seems to be working, but then the sorting by magnitude seems to fail after that ..

So, to counteract the default NULL ordering off sqlite, I have added the following:

```
 query.order_by(nullslast(self.model.m.asc()))
```

As per the documentation here:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.nullslast

However, my query is coming back with a **`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "NULLS": syntax error` **which I can't seem to decipher. My raw SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT body.apparent_magnitude AS body_apparent_magnitude, body.absolute_magnitude AS body_absolute_magnitude, body.distance AS body_distance, body.uid AS body_uid, body.name AS body_name, body.iau AS body_iau, body.ra AS body_ra, body.dec AS body_dec, body.constellation AS body_constellation, body.type AS body_type, body.hd AS body_hd, body.hr AS body_hr, body.hip AS body_hip, body.bd AS body_bd, body.flamsteed AS body_flamsteed, body.messier AS body_messier, body.ngc AS body_ngc, body.ic AS body_ic, body.simbad AS body_simbad 
FROM body ORDER BY CASE body.type WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? END, body.apparent_magnitude ASC NULLS LAST
```

```
[parameters: ('Other', 4, '*', 3, '**', 3, '*Ass', 3, 'OCl', 2, 'GCl', 2, 'G', 1, 'Cl+N', 0, 'PN', 0, 'HII', 0, 'DrkN', 0, 'EmN', 0, 'Neb', 0, 'RfN', 0, 'SNR', 0, 20, 0)]
```

One solution I have found is to run a coalesce command on the field that could be null, and provide an alternative value to ensure ordering (leaves the underlying data in place):

```
query.order_by(func.coalesce(Body.m, 99999).asc())
```